# Inverse of a totally unimodular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization, total-unimodularity

A unimodular matrix $M$ is a square integer matrix having determinant $+1$ or $−1$.
A totally unimodular matrix  (TU matrix) is a matrix for which every square non-singular submatrix is unimodular. A totally unimodular matrix need not be square itself. Obviously, any totally unimodular matrix has only $0$, $+1$ or $−1$ entries.

Now suppose a $n\times n$ non-singular matrix $A$ is totally unimodular. Can we prove that
$A^{-1}$ is also totally unimodular? Or if it is not correct, can we have a counterexample?

Comment: it seems that invertible TU matrices also form a group like unimodular matrices...but I don't have a proof yet.

Comment: Doesn't this follow from looking at the adjoint or cofactor marix?  Gerhard "Ask Me About Binary Matrices" Paseman, 2013.04.19

Comment: S. Sra: Good luck with that proof.  You might consider 1 1;0 1  meanwhile.  Gerhard "Not Grouplike Under Matrix Multiplication" Paseman, 2013.04.19

Comment: @Gerhard: The inverse of the matrix that you've mentioned is also TU...so I don't understand your comment???

Comment: S. Sra, I am suggesting that I don't know what group structure you are placing on the set of matrices.  For the two notions of multiplication I considered, the matrix    I gave does not help form a group.  Gerhard "How Do You Multiply Them?" Paseman, 2013.04.19

Comment: in my experiments, I multiplied in a modulo 2 style, so that all the $2$s and $-2$s were turned into 0s. That seemed to retain the TU property; but this seems rather brittle to make a group and perhaps you can find a counterexample to this product operation (ordinary mtx multiply followed by truncation).

Comment: @S. Sra. If you multiply modulo $2$, you cannot distinguish between $+1$ and $-1$. Therefore the minors are defined only modulo $2$, which means that they are either $0$ or $1$. Since every matrix should be TU modulo $2$, this notion in not interesting in ${\mathbb Z}_2$. It is only interesting in $\mathbb Z$, in which the product of TU matrices is not even unimodular in general. So the question about multiplication is just not a good one.

Comment: @Denis: True! I was stuck on trying to extend group structure to TU matrices just because unimodular ones form a group; but yes, it seems the question of mult. here is not the right way to go. But since we have inverses that are also TU, there is slightly more algebraic structure available, so it may be worth exploring...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is yes, because if $B=A^{-1}$, then we have an equality between minors:
$$B(I,J)=\pm\frac{A(J^c,I^c)}{\det A},$$
for every subsets $I,J\subset[[1,n]]$ of same cardinals. This formula generalizes that giving the entries of $A^{-1}$ in terms of minors of $A$. The $\pm$ sign is not essential to prove the stability of the TU class under inversion.

Comment: ah, good old Cramer's rule (essentially!)

Comment: Thank you very much. But I think the formula should be
$B(I,J) = \pm \frac{A(J^c, I^c)}{\det A}$.

Comment: @qianchi. Of course you're right. I'll edit.